# Trying to access Properties in Active Directory to add to a Database

Tags: c#, active-directory

Working on pulling user info from an AD based on an ID that is entered. The error I get is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type "string" to type "System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry"

happening here in the `Save` method:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
de = QueryAD(objSearchRolesViewModel.NID);
```

Opening the connection:

```
private DirectoryEntry GetDirectoryObject()
{
    DirectoryEntry oDE;
    oDE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myConnection");
    return oDE;
}
```

Querying AD:

```
public string QueryAD(string userNID)
{
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher
        {
            SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(""),
            //start searching from local domain
            Filter = userNID
        };

    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

    // start searching
    SearchResultCollection searchCollection = ds.FindAll();

    try
    {
        foreach (SearchResult result in searchCollection)
        {
            if (result.Properties.PropertyNames != null)
                foreach (string propKey in result.Properties.PropertyNames)
                {
                    // Display each of the values for the property identified by the property name.
                    foreach (object prop in result.Properties[propKey])
                    {
                        if ((propKey == "userPrincipalName"))
                        {
                            return prop.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }

            return "Unknown User";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Unknown User";
        }
}
```

Save new user:

```
public void SaveUser(SearchRolesViewModel objSearchRolesViewModel, string userID)
{
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
    de = QueryAD(objSearchRolesViewModel.NID);

    USERACCOUNT objUserAccount = new USERACCOUNT
        {
            HPID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.NewUserHealthPlans),
            DOMAIN = "Aeth",
            NTUSERID = objSearchRolesViewModel.User_Id,
            ROLEID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.UserRole),
            FIRSTNAME = GIVENNAME GOES HERE,
            LASTNAME = SURNAME GOES HERE,
            EMAIL = MAIL GOES HERE,
            ACTIVE = true/*Convert.ToBoolean(objSearchRolesViewModel.ActiveStatus)*/,
            DEFAULTPLANID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.NewUserPrimaryHealthPlan),
            CREATEID = userID,
            CREATEDATE = DateTime.Now,
            UPDATEID = userID,
            UPDATEDATE = DateTime.Now
        };

    _context.USERACCOUNTs.Add(objUserAccount);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I need to be able to access the properties from Active Directory and add them to what is being sent to the DB when a new user is added.

Comment: have you looked into using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement? It is much more convenient and easy to use.

Comment: @Jawad I looked into AccountManagement, but from what I read it can't be used with LDAP?

Comment: You can use ldap with principalContext. I'll try and put some code together with test sample in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple nit-picky things:

> Opening the connection

Creating a `DirectoryEntry` object doesn't actually open any connection. That is how almost all of Microsoft's libraries work: constructors do not make any I/O requests. The first network request is made when you first start using the object.

Also, `new DirectoryEntry("")` has exactly the same effect as `new DirectoryEntry()` - the empty string doesn't get you anything. But also, if you don't set the `SearchRoot` property, it will automatically set it to the current domain anyway. So you don't even need to set it unless you need to set it to a different domain or OU.

Now on to answering the question:

You have gotten a couple answers already, but they aren't ideal. You certainly can use the [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement) namespace if you want, which is just a wrapper around [`System.DirectoryServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices) to make things easier. But like all things that make things easier, it does so at the cost of performance. It always has worse performance over using `System.DirectoryServices` directly, yourself. One reason is because whenever a [`UserPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal) object is created, it retrieves *every attribute that has a value* for the account. You probably aren't using every attribute.

If you can wrap your head around using `DirectoryEntry`/`DirectorySearcher` yourself, you will have better performing code.

Jawad's answer will also work, but it has one key issue that will slow down your code: `DirectorySearcher` will return all the attributes you request. You already set `PropertiesToLoad`, which is good - it will limit the results to only the attributes you need. But if you use `GetDirectoryEntry()`, that info is lost. If you then start using `.Properties` on the `DirectoryEntry`, it will make a new network request and ask for *all attributes that have values*. That can be a lot of data that you aren't using, apart from being a second network request that you could avoid.

I would suggest just returning a [`SearchResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresult) from `QueryAD`, which will let you use the data that was returned in the search.

You can also use [`FindOne()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findone) instead of `FindAll()`, since you are only using the first result anyway. This will make AD stop looking after it finds one result. Just test for `null` in case the user wasn't found.

```cs
public SearchResult QueryAD(string userNID)
{
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(userNID) {
        PropertiesToLoad = {"givenname", "sn", "mail"}
    };

    return ds.FindOne();
}

public void SaveUser(SearchRolesViewModel objSearchRolesViewModel, string userID)
{
    var result = QueryAD(objSearchRolesViewModel.NID);

    if (result == null)
    {
        //user wasn't found!
    }

    USERACCOUNT objUserAccount = new USERACCOUNT
        {
            HPID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.NewUserHealthPlans),
            DOMAIN = "Aeth",
            NTUSERID = objSearchRolesViewModel.User_Id,
            ROLEID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.UserRole),
            FIRSTNAME = (string) result.Properties["givenName"]?[0],
            LASTNAME = (string) result.Properties["sn"]?[0],
            EMAIL = (string) result.Properties["mail"]?[0],
            ACTIVE = true/*Convert.ToBoolean(objSearchRolesViewModel.ActiveStatus)*/,
            DEFAULTPLANID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.NewUserPrimaryHealthPlan),
            CREATEID = userID,
            CREATEDATE = DateTime.Now,
            UPDATEID = userID,
            UPDATEDATE = DateTime.Now
        };

    _context.USERACCOUNTs.Add(objUserAccount);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The `Properties` of a `SearchResult` will always present properties as arrays, even if they are single-valued attributes in AD. This is different than `DirectoryEntry`. But that is the reason for the `[0]` in `result.Properties["givenName"]?[0] as string`. The [`?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) is to test for `null`, because if the attribute is not set in AD, then it won't appear in the `Properties` collection at all.

I wrote an article about [getting better performance when programming with AD](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html), with a focus on C#. You might enjoy reading it.

Comment: use de.RefreshCache() to load specific properties into the cache before you use them ?

Comment: @Kiquenet Correct.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `QueryAD(objSearchRolesViewModel.NID);` returns a string but you are assigning it to a DirectoryEntity. This wont work.

```
public void SaveUser(SearchRolesViewModel objSearchRolesViewModel, string userID)
        {
           DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
                de = QueryAD(objSearchRolesViewModel.NID); // <--- This is the issue.
...
```

Look up DirectoryEntry from the QueryAD function and return that object to make your call work.

```
public string QueryAD(string userNID) // You will need to return DirectoryEntry to make your code work.
        {
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher
```

EDIT:

I find using UserPrincipal with PrincipalContext to be much simpler. Look up PrincipalContext by using your domain name and provide creds if not running with domain account. Then, simply, lookup user by SamAccountName, Name/ID or DistinguishedName.

You will need, `'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement'` nuget package for Principal usage.

```
public static UserPrincipal QueryAD(string UserName)
    {

        PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Aeth", "user", "password");

        // Without creds if the account running the code is already a domain account
        //PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Aeth"); 

        // You can search the account by SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, UserPrincipalName or SID
        return UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Name, UserName);


    }
    public void SaveUser(SearchRolesViewModel objSearchRolesViewModel, string userID)
    {
        UserPrincipal user = QueryAD(objSearchRolesViewModel.User_Id);

        USERACCOUNT objUserAccount = new USERACCOUNT
        {

            HPID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.NewUserHealthPlans),
            DOMAIN = "Aeth",
            NTUSERID = objSearchRolesViewModel.User_Id,
            ROLEID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.UserRole),
            FIRSTNAME = user.GivenName, // Get FirstName
            LASTNAME = user.Surname,    // Get LastName
            EMAIL = user.EmailAddress,  // Get Email Address
            ACTIVE =  user.Enabled,     // Get User Status
            DEFAULTPLANID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.NewUserPrimaryHealthPlan),
            CREATEID = userID,
            CREATEDATE = DateTime.Now,
            UPDATEID = userID,
            UPDATEDATE = DateTime.Now
        };
        _context.USERACCOUNTs.Add(objUserAccount);
        _context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean in your answer. The only place I see DirectoryEntry in the function is when I set it to SearchRoot. Where would it be returned?

Comment: You are returning a string in your QueryAD method but assigning it to a directory directoryentry variable.

Comment: right. How do I take the string that I've returned and use it in my Save method?

Comment: Now the error is happening where I return "prop.ToString()" and "Unknown User."

Comment: @MatthewWright Added two functions two replace the three methods you have. Use of PrincipalContext and UserPrincipal makes things very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Following is your code that uses DirectoryEntry method. Make sure you add credentials if you are running this code with account that does not have access to AD.

**Method to search AD**

```
 public DirectoryEntry QueryAD(string UserName)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher
                {
                    SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(),
                    //start searching from local domain
                    Filter = "(&" +
                    "(objectClass=user)" +
                    "(name=" + UserName + "))" // This is Username
                };

                // start searching
                return ds.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("error occured while querying AD");
            }
        }
```

**Method to Check if Account is Active**

```
        private bool IsActive(DirectoryEntry de)
        {
            if (de.NativeGuid == null) return false;

            int flags = (int)de.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;

            return !Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0002);
        }
```

**Method to Save the User to your DB**

```
        public void SaveUser(SearchRolesViewModel objSearchRolesViewModel, string userID)
        {
            DirectoryEntry userEntry = QueryAD(objSearchRolesViewModel.User_Id);
            if (userEntry == null) 
            {
               //Handle error where No User was Found.
               throw new ApplicationException("User Not Found");
            }

            USERACCOUNT objUserAccount = new USERACCOUNT
            {

                HPID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.NewUserHealthPlans),
                DOMAIN = "Aeth",
                NTUSERID = objSearchRolesViewModel.User_Id,
                ROLEID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.UserRole),
                FIRSTNAME = userEntry.Properties["givenname"].Value.ToString(), 
                LASTNAME = userEntry.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString(),
                EMAIL = userEntry.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString(),
                ACTIVE = IsActive(userEntry),
                DEFAULTPLANID = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchRolesViewModel.NewUserPrimaryHealthPlan),
                CREATEID = userID,
                CREATEDATE = DateTime.Now,
                UPDATEID = userID,
                UPDATEDATE = DateTime.Now
            };
            _context.USERACCOUNTs.Add(objUserAccount);
            _context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance yet to try it out, but I will today and update you.